# How to reset shortcuts (.lnk file) in windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, file-shortcut

I was trying to make PyCharm default for .ipynb files instead of VS code, but I accidentally chose the shortcut of Pycharm and now **all my .lnk files are opened by PyCharm**. I tried to follow some solutions on the net such as *deleting the "userchoice" folder* in the directory below but there are **only two** folders in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk

it (screenshots down below). I also tried deleting all files and associating them again from cmd but what I deleted then came back.

I don't know what to do.

[OpenWithList folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dPw3.png)

[OpenWithProdigs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHSKV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the entire `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.lnk` registry folder (subkey).

Also delete `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\lnkfile` if it exists.

The primary source of file associations is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, which in modern Windows versions is a merged view of the per-user HKCU\Software\Classes and the system-wide HKLM\Software\Classes. Your changes were stored in the HKCU subkey – deleting them will allow Explorer to again use the system-wide association that's stored in HKLM.

(Be careful to not delete anything from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, however.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your lightning fast reply :)